# It takes long time to built file

Tags: visual-studio-code, json, uplatex

I made this file:

```latex
\documentclass[uplatex, dvipdfmx]{jsarticle}
\begin{document}

\LaTeX

\begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2  = 5
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2  = 13
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and then built the file in VScode.

It takes 10 second to build such a small file.
I think it takes too long time so I am asking this question.

Here is the log (`<my username>` and `(My Laptop name)` were replaced by me):

```
[13:55:28] RECIPES command invoked.
[13:55:28] BUILD command invoked.
[13:55:28] The document of the active editor: file:///c%3A/Users/<<my username>>/Dropbox/My%20PC%20%28My Laptop name%29/Desktop/test_latex/test.tex
[13:55:28] The languageId of the document: latex
[13:55:28] Current workspace folders: ["file:///c:/Users/<my username>/Dropbox/My PC (My Laptop name)/Desktop/test_latex"]
[13:55:28] Current workspaceRootDir: c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex
[13:55:28] Found root file from active editor: c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.tex
[13:55:28] Keep using the same root file: c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.tex
[13:55:28] Building root file: c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.tex
[13:55:28] Build root file c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.tex
[13:55:28] Recipe step 1: latexmk, -pdfdvi,c:/Users/<my username>/Dropbox/My PC (My Laptop name)/Desktop/test_latex/test
[13:55:28] Recipe step env: undefined
[13:55:28] cwd: c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex
[13:55:28] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 23388.
[13:55:37] LaTeX log parsed with 0 messages.
[13:55:37] Recipe of length 1 finished. PID: 23388.
[13:55:37] Successfully built c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.tex.
[13:55:37] No PDF viewer connected for c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.pdf
[13:55:37] Parse fls file.
[13:55:37] Fls file found: c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.fls
[13:55:37] Parse aux file: c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.aux
[13:55:37] SyncTex after build invoked.
[13:55:37] Execute external SyncTeX command: command C:/Users/create310/AppData/Local/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe, args -reuse-instance,c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.pdf,-forward-search,c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.tex,11,-inverse-search,"C:\Users\create310\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" -r -g "%f:%l"
[13:55:37] Open external viewer for syncTeX from c:\Users\<my username>\Dropbox\My PC (My Laptop name)\Desktop\test_latex\test.pdf
```

and here is my `setting.json`:

```json
{    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": 
    [
        {
            "name": "latexmk", 
            "command": "latexmk", 
            "args": 
            [
                "-pdfdvi", 
                "%DOC%", 
            ],
        },
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": 
    [
        {
            "name": "latexmk", 
            "tools": 
            [
                "latexmk", 
            ]
        },        
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.clean.fileTypes": 
    [
        "*.aux", "*.bbl", "*.blg", "*.idx", "*.ind", "*.lof", "*.lot", "*.out", "*.toc", "*.acn", "*.acr", "*.alg", 
        "*.glg", "*.glo", "*.gls", "*.ist", "*.fls", "*.log", "*.fdb_latexmk", "*.synctex.gz", 
        "_minted*", "*.nav", "*.snm", "*.vrb", 
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "onFailed", 
    "latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "never", 
    "latex-workshop.synctex.afterBuild.enabled": true, 
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "external", 

    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.synctex.command": 
    "C:/Users/create310/AppData/Local/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe",
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.synctex.args": [
    "-reuse-instance",
    "%PDF%",
    "-forward-search",
    "%TEX%",
    "%LINE%",
    "-inverse-search",
    "\"C:\\Users\\create310\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin\\code.cmd\" -r -g \"%f:%l\""
]
}
```

and here is my `.latexmkrc`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$latex                       = 'uplatex -synctex=1 -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error';
$latex_silent                = 'uplatex -synctex=1 -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error';
$bibtex                      = 'upbibtex';
$dvipdf                      = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S';
$max_repeat                  = 3;
$pdf_mode                    = 3;
$pvc_view_file_via_temporary = 0;
```

Why dose my file take so long time to built?

Is  the message `[13:55:37] LaTeX log parsed with 0 messages.`
bottle neck?

Comment: This is strange. In my (linux) system: `time (uplatex -synctex=1 lulla.tex && dvipdfmx lulla.dvi)`  gives `0.39s user 0.09s system 97% cpu 0.495 total` so more or less half a second.

Comment: are you sure you were not experiencing slow sync to dropbox, try a local filesystem first.

Comment: And what is the contents of the LaTeX log file (called `test.log` for the file `test.tex`)? Maybe that will tell you which part of the compilation process is responsible.